# fs.watch(__dirname + "/arquivo.txt", function(event, filename)

Tags: html, node.js

```
fs.watch(__dirname + "/arquivo.txt", function(event, filename)
```

what has to be given instead of `arquivo.txt`? 
My file name is `doc.txt` and it is located in : `C:/projects/test/`

Comment: You want to get rid of that `__dirname` and put in the path.

Comment: Edit your question and add a understandable title

Comment: Please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Snippet to access file in your path (C:/projects/test/doc.txt)

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.watch("C:/projects/test/doc.txt" , (eventType, filename) => {
    console.log(`event type is: ${eventType}`);
    if (filename) {
      console.log(`filename provided: ${filename}`);
    } else {
      console.log('filename not provided');
    }
  });
```

**__dirname** - Directory name of the current running module. You can use __dirname to access the file inside your current running module.